# video and audio processing library in python

Tags: python, video, audio

Which video/audio libraries are available in Python to recognize a certain audio pattern within a video recording?
I'm trying to exclude the beginning of the recording from the video file (skipping up to the particular audio pattern) and therefore I'd need a way to

- scan the file from its beginning
- recognize the audio pattern (a particular piece of music always the same)
- record/copy the rest of the video recording from that point on.

Video Details

Format :- Real Media ( not matters though as i can convert it to something more )

Length :- varies from 18 - 24 minutes

Running the media info tool on one such video gives the following details

```
Video
ID                               : 1
Format                           : RealVideo 4
Codec ID                         : RV40
Codec ID/Info                    : Based on AVC (H.264), Real Player 9
Duration                         : 19mn 18s
Bit rate                         : 195 Kbps
Width                            : 332 pixels
Height                           : 248 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 4:3
Frame rate                       : 23.976 fps
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.099
Stream size                      : 27.0 MiB (84%)

Audio
ID                               : 0
Format                           : Cooker
Codec ID                         : cook
Codec ID/Info                    : Based on G.722.1, Real Player 6
Duration                         : 19mn 20s
Bit rate                         : 32.0 Kbps
Channel(s)                       : 2 channels
Sampling rate                    : 44.1 KHz
Bit depth                        : 16 bits
Stream size                      : 4.43 MiB (14%)
```

---

Original question:

So the other day i revisited an animation serial dragon ball z and was irritated by the video which i had. Each episode consists of approx 24 minutes and each of them has a full recap of the previous one and an ending music combined total of around 6-8 minutes.

I noticed that each video has a same audio when the recap finishes and the new name of the video comes.I recorded this audio in a seperate file.

I wanted to ask if there is any way in python i can do the following by coding :=

1. Scan the audio to match the recorded audio of the title name to know the exact time of actual video starting.
2. Save the video as starting from that point.

I don't know the difficulty of doing this so do tell if its possible.

I would be thankful if you can tell any library that does provide me the tools to do so and give me some tips as to how should i go on.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Pardon my edit of the question. I'm trying to help since as-is this question prompted a "close as not a real question" vote.  It was probably perceived as too vague and broad. I tried to reframe/reword as a more SO-worthy question. It remains broad, but probably useful/interesting.  In a nutshell, what are useful pointers (library names, algorithms, gotchas...) for someone who is trying to process video as indicated.

Comment: user506710, can you further improve the question by indicating the video format, the length and characteristic of the "marker music" etc?

Comment: no problems :) i guess it helps if anybody understands more clearly :) though i am mystified by the reason that it is called broad... is matching the audio to get the starting time really too broad ? After i get the time then i can cut the video from that point ....

Comment: @mjv the reason i did'nt mention the format was because i did'nt want to restrict the question ... i just thought that if say there's a library for .avi i can convert it to .avi through batch processing... i don't understand what you mean by marker though ...

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, speech recognition (that also expose lower level functionality as scoring the similitude between two sounds) is only supported in Python [through windows libraries](http://code.google.com/p/pyspeech/) or the [dragon naturally speaking API](http://code.google.com/p/dragonfly/).

Once the marker is found, you could use an external library like [this](http://pymedia.org/) or [this](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/) to cut the video as per requirements.

EDIT: A google search also returned [pyofa](http://furius.ca/pyofa/) a wrapper around [musicip-libofa](http://code.google.com/p/musicip-libofa/) which is an [acousting fingerprint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) library.